# Intent Service stays open after app closed

Tags: android, intentservice

Ive created an app which needs to run an intent service while the application is closed if two values are out of sync(eg. 2 of 3). The intent service updates a text view within my application which will display the two values using a BroadcastReceiver.

Also the intent service is created in one activity but should be stopped in another. The two values are based on a GPS location update and that location being sent through a web service method. At points the GPS may update location and the web service might not due to limited connectivity to mobile data/wifi therefore leaving the values out of balance(1 of 3) and if the user closes the app this needs to continuously run until the value reaches 3 of 3(the GPS stops updating when app is closed).

The intent should run until the values are in sync again even if application has been closed. How would i keep this running whilst the app is closed and then stop it when the the values are in sync

Answer (score 0):

Because an IntentService is like a Thread. It's designed to run aslong as it takes to finish onHandleIntent().

Use a regular Service and control it with stopService or stopself() if you want to manage the lifecycle.

edit: by the way, why do you mix asynctask and intentservices at all? Use one of them but dont mix it. AsyncTask handles all. Background Threading and processing in the mainUI. Anyway, for using GPS you should decide to use a regular Service and (maybe) create a Thread within the Services onStartCommand().

Comment: The AsyncTask is used for running the Web Service method but it stopped once the application closed an activity. Running it within the IntentService allowed me to use it across all activities and i could stop it when the whole application had completed the updates ie 3 of 3. The GPS runs within a regular service whereas the WebService method is within the IntentService. The onHandleIntent ends when the updates are finished ie 3 of 3 or it is supposed to finish when that happens

Comment: Then use the IntentService to run your webservices WITHOUT an extra asynctask which seems to be worthless in your case. The IntentService will run aslong as it takes to finish everything. Why dont you just wait until the onLocationChanged received and update your Webservice? Keeping it open until you recevie a new location (at least 3) doesnt make sense at all.

Comment: That is what i am doing 3 of 3 is just an example. the app is supposed to go 1 of 1, 2 of 2, etc but sometimes due to lack of connection to the network a WebService update cannot occur and the application will become out of sync ie 1 of 2, 2 of 3. The user should still be able to leave the application and it should update until the values are equal. The GPS updates end when the user leaves the app. So if a user has the GPS updates 5 times and leaves the app this will no longer update. If the web service update is out of sync say at 1. This should update until it reaches the GPS number( 5 of 5)

Comment: That's not true. The service will run aslong as you keep it running. Use a regular Service and RETURN_STICKY. If the GC want to kill it, it will come back onec it has enough ressources available for the Service. Within the Service you validate a) the sync-state and b) the count of GPS locations received. Store it locally and re-read it as soon as the services onStartCommand get executed again (when it got killed by GC)

Comment: My GPS service runs correctly i have wrote code for the GPS to stop when the user leaves the app. My problem is with the Web Services method. I want this to run until it equals the GPS. My problem I was having with a regular Service is that it starts in one activity and should end in another when the updates are finished. This requires a TextView to display these updates on both pages I figured using a Broadcast Receiver to display the updates on both pages would be the easiest way to do this. Can i not implement onStartCommand from an IntentService?

Comment: Please read my solution again. Use a Service with RETURN_STICKY which handles your webservice and synch it at the startup of the onStartCommand() in case the service has been killed. Store a SYNCHState somewhere to let the webservice know when it should stop (when its finished synching)

Comment: np. Please dont forget to rate up if this helped you and update your code onec you have used the solution mentioned :-)

Comment: Unfortunately my rating isnt high enough to do so :( Or i would!